# X11 error: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)

Tags: x11

What underlying problem does this imply? Which integer parameter is out-of-range? Which part of the source code?
And most importantly, how can I fix the problem?

```
[vo/opengl/x11] X11 error: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
[vo/opengl/x11] Type: 0, display: 0x7f264c43f950, resourceid: 0, serial: 3f
[vo/opengl/x11] Error code: 2, request code: 9a, minor code: 3
```

Comment: The best I can do with the information is to say that the error is in a part of the source code that is not shown here. What have you done to find the error? When was the last time that you ran your unit tests?

Answer (score 2):

> `[vo/opengl/x11] Error code: 2, request code: 9a, minor code: 3`

That error is generated by an extension request: all request codes >= 128 are reserved for extensions (0x9a = 154).

You'll have to first get the extension which is using that 154 opcode:

```
$ xdpyinfo -queryExtensions | grep 'opcode: 154'
    XFree86-VidModeExtension  (opcode: 154, base error: 175)
```

Your Xserver may allocate the opcodes differently; assuming that it's `XF86VidMode` as on mine, you can look up the minor code (3) in the protocol headers (or in the [xcb xml spec](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xcb/proto/tree/src)) of that extension:

```
grep 'X_.*\<3\>' /usr/include/X11/extensions/xf86vmproto.h
#define X_XF86VidModeSwitchMode         3
```

In that case, it's `XF86VidModeSwitchMode(dpy, screen, zoom)`.

Of course, the guy who wrote that program could've set a better X11 error handler, instead of that `code: hex` crap (the default X11 error handler, at least with a newer X11 library, is much better). But then, where would've been the fun in it?

Comment: should be obvious, but just in case for X Version 11, XListExtensions(3) and XQueryExtension(3) can be used to reverse the request code in software